# Jquery on submit without looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

I am making an event where the page checks if it needs to submit the data via POST or if simple ajax calls is fine.  IE: There is a file and it needs to handle the upload if no file submit the data and continue using the page.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) { 
     e.preventDefault();
     if($(this).find('[name=file]').val()) { // HAS FILE SUBMIT
          /*
              If I use $(this).submit() then it just loops.  I figured return true might work or putting e.preventDefault(); after this code
          */
     }


     // If it made it past that if then does ajax things that are fine.
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use `this.submit()` instead to actually submit the form, and not just trigger the event handler ?

Comment: @adeneo that is the correct answer, please post it and I will accept it.  If you use the jquery this it will just loop.  I should have tried that as well.  Other answer is unsalvageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery's `$(this).submit()` will trigger the event handler, and prevent the default action, so the form never submits, it just loops instead.

To stop that from happening, use the native `this.submit()` instead.

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('[name=file]').val()) { // HAS FILE SUBMIT
         this.submit();
    } else {
         $.ajax(options); // ...etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Might not be a bad idea to explain the difference(s) between `this` and `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but can't you just test for file first, and then, if there is no file, do a prevent default (or return false)?

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) { 
     if($(this).find('[name=file]').val()) {
        return true;
     }
     else {
         e.preventDefault();
         // Do AJAX 
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, and I said I already tried that in the comments, it does not work.  Ahh, I see the comment has to be scrolled over and you did not read that I wrote that already.